# Null pointer exception from the lights() command from the processing2.0 library for openGL

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, processing, lighting

I am trying to implement a lighted cube using openGL and the processing2.0 libraries.  However, when I try to call any lighting method from the processing libraries (lights(), directionalLight(), etc) I get a null pointer error when I try to run it.  Here's the method:

```
private void render(GLAutoDrawable drawable)
{
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    //Gets the drawable object which performs the rendering

    PGraphics3D pg = new PGraphics3D();

    gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    //Clears the color buffer

    pg.directionalLight(51, 102, 126, 0, -1, 0);

    pg.ambientLight(51, 102, 126);

    pg.specular(204, 102, 0);

    pg.ambient(51, 26, 0);

    glutSolidCube(1);

//      pg.box(1);

}
```

Comment: Why don’t you use the processing functions like [box()](http://processing.org/reference/box_.html)?

Comment: I tried substituting the 'glutSolidCube(1);' command for the command 'pg.box(1);', and I still get the same null pointer exception.

Comment: But do you really need to use the OpenGL functions directly?

Comment: I don't necessarily need to use the glutSolidCube command, I just know that it works whereas I still get errors when I try to use the box() command with a filling and no light.  Now eclipse is telling me that ambientLight() is not available with a PGraphics renderer, and is returning a nullPointerException with either the PGraphics3D or the PGraphicsOpenGL object

Comment: Is it even possible to use the processing functions within a java openGL program?  Or is this attempt just doomed from the start?

Comment: Follow [these](https://forum.processing.org/topic/tip-processing-2-0-in-eclipse-with-opengl) steps to work with OpenGL and Processing in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a cube with lightning using the build-in Processing functions. The P3D renderer internally uses OpenGL, too.

```
float angle = 0.0;
float step = 0.01;

void setup(){
  size(400, 400, P3D);
  noStroke();
}

void draw(){
  background(0);
  directionalLight(126, 126, 126, 0, 0, -1);
  ambientLight(102, 102, 102);
  translate(width/2, height/2, 0);
  rotateX(angle*0.1);
  rotateY(angle);
  angle += step;
  box(200);
}
```